# JS onclick issue to call images of css sprites

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-sprites

I've created a JS that upon clicking an image performs a certain action. ATM all images are loaded individually and called with this function:

```
var array_colors = [];
$('#input_59_20 > li.active').each(function(index){
    var img = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    array_colors.push(img);
});`
```

The thing is that the page loads relatively slow as there are many http requests.
I therefore decided to modify the page to call on 1 css sprite instead of 50 small image files, however cant figure out how to call the individual images loaded via the sprite.
An example call for one of the images of the css sprite is:     `<i class="sprite sprite-sb31-choco"></i>`

thanks for the help.
Best regards,
Amir

Comment: I think since sprite is a image in itself, so it will load completely. But, you can get the desired image inside sprite using `background-position`. [EXAMPLE LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

Comment: *"cant figure out how to call the individual images loaded via the sprite"* can you clarify what you're goal is?  There are no individual images, there is only one `src` tag and one image.

Comment: Use CSS Sprites -  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: Hi, sorry for not explaining well. In terms of css the images are all placed into the div properly using background-position, etc. The thing is that I want to interact with the individual parts of the css sprite via JS (given that the src of the parts is always the same sprite).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correctly then it seems you are approaching it in a wrong way. What you need is image mapping. So that you can load the whole image in one go and map parts of the image to be clicked on and do something.

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area class="imgClick" shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="#" alt="Sun">
  <area class="imgClick" shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="#" alt="Mercury">
  <area class="imgClick" shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="#" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

And as `href` attribute is mandatory in area tag you need something like the following to do something other than redirect:

```
<script>
    $(".imgClick").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        /*
           your code here
        */
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry that I didnt explain my dilemma well. Please see the link below as example. As you see, when you click on any of the balls a JS creates a visual overlay simulating the selected colors. I wish to do the same thing but instead of loading many individual images I want to load only 1 sprite. I didnt quite understand how to do the image mapping @rmrinmoy, Ill have a look at it tomorrow to see if that could be a solution.  cormilu.com.br/loja/diy/monte-seu-fio-de-luz/  . Thanks for your help

Comment: For this particular thing map will not help. You need to use sprite and calculate the correct position of the clicked overlay on click. You can give every overlay a class and on click add the class to the desired element. And in CSS change the sprite background position calling it with the concatenated class.